# Watchdog daemon doesn't start at boot

Tags: systemd, raspberry-pi, raspbian, init-script, watchdog

I'm using a Raspberry Pi B, with Raspbian.
After upgrading to Jessie, watchdog daemon doesn't start at boot anymore. Starting it manually using "sudo service watchdog start" does work.
I tried:

- purging and reinstalling watchdog
- `update-rc.d watchdog defaults && update-rc.d watchdog enable`
- `systemctl enable watchdog` produces this error:

> The unit files have no [Install] section. They are not meant to be enabled using systemctl.

I checked

- syslog with systemd verbosity on debug, no results. Other than the watchdog device nothing is mentioned.
- `systemctl list-units | grep -i watchdog` is emtpy (unless I started it manually)
- My default runlevel is 5 and the priority of watchdog in `/etc/rc5.d/` is also 5.

What else can I try?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Open

```
/lib/systemd/system/watchdog.service
```

and add

```
[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

Systemd needs the [Install]-Section for a Unit to know how it should enable/disable the Unit.

Answer (score 1):

Services installed on the system come with default unit files that are stored in the `/usr/lib/systemd/system/` directory. System Administrators should not modify these files directly, therefore any customization must be confined to configuration files in the `/etc/systemd/system/` directory.

[Link...](https://access.redhat.com/documentation/en-US/Red_Hat_Enterprise_Linux/7/html/System_Administrators_Guide/sect-Managing_Services_with_systemd-Unit_Files.html#sect-Managing_Services_with_systemd-Unit_File_Modify)

Update:

Just make link for default config /lib/systemd/system/[service name].service to /etc/systemd/system/multi-user.target.wants/[service name].service, aka:

```
# ln /lib/systemd/system/watchdog.service /etc/systemd/system/multi-user.target.wants/watchdog.service
```

Then reboot system:

```
# reboot
```

And check what service starts automatically:

```
# systemctl status watchdog.service
```

Comment: Can you be more specific with your answer? Please don't rely on outer links, as they may be dead any time.

Comment: Thomas, I expanded my answer